# What should i do with custom GROUP BY in sql and php?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to make sub group in group by (SQL).
in my case, I want to make classified detail in group detail which it come from two different column, for more detail, check this out :

I've sql table like this :

```
+----+-------+--------+-------+
| No | data1 | detail | price |
+----+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | ID1   | Food   | $ 100 |
|  2 | ID1   | Drink  | $ 25  |
|  3 | ID2   | Drink  | $ 25  |
|  4 | ID1   | Snack  | $ 50  |
|  5 | ID2   | Snack  | $ 50  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+
```

I want to make result in my php page like this :

```
+----+-------+--------+-------+
| No | detail_lunch   | price |
+----+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Food           |       |
|    |  - ID1         | $ 100 |
|  2 | Snack          |       |
|    |  - ID1         | $ 25  |
|    |  - ID2         | $ 25  |
|  3 | Drink          |       |
|    |  - ID1         | $ 10  |
|    |  - ID2         | $ 10  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+
```

I already tried with GROUP CONCAT as below :

**Controller :**

```
$d['data'] = $this->db->query("select detail_item, GROUP_CONCAT (detail) detail_lunch 
            from table ORDER BY detail_lunch ASC");
```

**Views :**

```
<?php
    foreach($data->result_array() as $d)
    {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d['detail_lunch']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d['price']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        $no++;
    }
?>
```

My code above not working, 
is there any suggestion to solve my problem?

thanks...

Comment: Use groupby detail, data

Comment: could you please detail it in code?

Comment: "table" is a poor name for a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not needed since you're not using an aggregate function *(combining two rows of values into a single value)*, you are attempting to create a pivot table, *(joining two columns under a related column as multiple rows)*. You only need to `ORDER BY detail ASC,  data1 ASC`, iterate over the resultset to display the `detail` when it changes, otherwise display the `data1` and `price`

### Example: https://3v4l.org/7tVDS

**Query:**

```
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT data1, detail, price 
        FROM table ORDER BY detail ASC, data1 ASC');
```

**View:**

```
<?php

//...

$no = 1;
$currentDetail = null;
foreach ($data->result_array() as $d) { 
    if ($d['detail'] !== $currentDetail) { ?>
    <!-- Only Show the Detail when changed -->
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d['detail']; ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 <!-- Always show the data1/price on subsequent row -->
  <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>- <?php echo $d['data1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $d['price']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
    $currentDetail = $d['detail'];
} ?>
```

**Result:**

```
| 1 | Food |
| - ID1 | $ 100 |
| 2 | Drink |
| - ID1 | $ 25 |
| - ID2 | $ 25 |
| 3 | Snack |
| - ID1 | $ 50 |
| - ID2 | $ 50 |
```

Alternatively you can manipulate how the data is displayed in your view, such as using an unordered list `ul` in the detail table column `td` along with price. By  using PHP to organize the values how you would like them to be displayed in your view, in an organized associative array.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/8sIrR

```
$dataArray = [];
foreach ($data as $d) { 
   if (!array_key_exists($d['detail'], $dataArray)) {
        $dataArray[$d['detail']] = [];
   }
   $dataArray[$d['detail']][] = $d;
}


//...

$no = 1;
foreach ($dataArray as $detail => $d) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $detail; ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach ($d as $v) { ?>
                <li><?php echo $v['data1']; ?> <?php echo $v['price']; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Query is the problem . 
Select detail_lunch from table group by details.
Then you can use if statement on that result.
I will update my answer after I get to work on my computer.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.